# Integer representation for day of the week

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I would like to convert a date object its integer representation for the day of week in C#. Right now, I am parsing a XML file in order to retrieve the date and storing that info in a string. It is in the following format:

"2008-12-31T00:00:00.0000000+01:00"

How can I take this and convert it into a number between 1 and 7 for the day of the week that it represents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(Int32)Convert.ToDateTime("2008-12-31T00:00:00.0000000+01:00").DayOfWeek + 1
```

Answer (score 9):

If you load that into a DateTime varible, DateTime exposes an enum for the day of the week that you could cast to int.

Comment: To parse the XML date to a DateTime, I suggest using the XmlConvert class.

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2008-12-31T00:00:00.0000000+01:00");
int dayOfWeek = (int)date.DayOfWeek + 1; //DayOfWeek is 0 based, you wanted 1 based
```

Answer (score 4):

(int)System.DateTime.Parse("2008-12-31T00:00:00.0000000+01:00").DayOfWeek + 1